# tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently in the middle of a recorded Python lecture and I think the version of python the teacher is using is outdated and he is writing a tkinter program but after copying it I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lecture Class 11.py", line 35, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="Me With My 5th Place.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "Me With My 5th Place.jpg"
```

And here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.button_clicks = 0
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label1 = Label(self)
        label1.image = photo
        label1.grid()
        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.button1["text"] = "Click me!!!"
        self.button1["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.button2 = Button(self)
        self.button2["text"] = "Reset click counter"
        self.button2["command"] = self.reset_count
        self.button.grid(row=3, column= 1)

    def update_count(self):
        self.button_clicks += 1
        self.button1["text"] = "Total clicks: " + str(self.button_clicks)

    def res_count(self):
        self.button_clicks = 0
        self.button["text"] = "I am reset. Click me!!!"

root = Tk()
root.title("CP101 click counter")
root.geometry("400x400")

photo = PhotoImage(file="Me With My 5th Place.jpg")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please make sure above code is in fact a [mcve].

Comment: The above code returns _multiple_ errors _none_ of which is the error you claim to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite normal.  Tkinter does not yet support .jpg files.  To solve the problem you want to either to convert your file to .png, .gif or similar or use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to add support for .jpg files.

Comment: You need to add `self` prefix to `label1.image = photo` and 
        `label1.grid()`

Comment: `reset_count` doesn't exist in your script.  Might be `res_count` idk

Comment: @IsaacVolpe And apart from what I listed above and `self.button.grid(row=3,column= 1)` not being defined it seems OK.

Answer (score 10):

.jpg is not supported by default by `tkinter`. You can use .jpg files using `PIL`:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    label = tk.Label(root)
    img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg")
    label.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label['image'] = label.img

    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is Pillow an included module?

Comment: You mean by default install of python?

Comment: @IsaacVolpe  No you have to install it separately.  `pip3 install pillow`